# How to make a patch's overflow visible on a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a rectangle on my figure such that it overflows on both ends and this overflow is visible.

### Example

```py
 from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = [5, 5], dpi = 100)
 a = plt.Rectangle(tuple((0.4, -0.2)), 0.1, 1.2, color = 'black', alpha=0.8)
 ax.add_patch(a)
 plt.show(block=True)
 fig.tight_layout()
```

The previous code snippet produces

[image]

but I want the rectangle to overflow

[image]

### Things I have tried

I have tried using `zorder` but that doesn't seem to be the solution. I have tried searching online and Stackoverflow but I have not found a similar problem.

### Note (Restriction)

I know I could just draw on my plot explicitly using Paint, Powerpoint or similar, but I am restricted in doing that since I am performing a simulation (which produces a gif), so I need to do this natively in Matpotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `clip_on=False`:

```
a = plt.Rectangle(tuple((0.4, -0.1)), 0.1, 1.2, color = 'black', alpha=0.8, clip_on=False)
```

Note the slightly changed rectangle values to align the bar.

[image]

---

From [matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on.html) as a brief explanation:

> Set whether the artist uses clipping.
>
> When False artists will be visible outside of the Axes which can lead
> to unexpected results.